# Is there a way to use my current SSH connection for an SCP transfer?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp

I'm already connected to the server via SSH. How can I transfer files from it to the machine I'm connected from using SCP and the current SSH connection?

Comment: which platform/app on server and client?

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com

Comment: @Paul R: Yeah, you're right. sh/w/coulda...

Comment: @Paulo: Recent Ubuntu on both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zssh (zmodem like app for ssh).

But if you are only trying to avoid ssh prompting again for the password, just put the client host public key (generated running ssh-keygen once) on the servers ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

from "apt-cache show zssh":

```
Description: interactive file transfers over ssh
 zssh (Zmodem SSH) is a program for interactively transferring files to a
 remote machine  while using  the secure  shell (ssh).  It is intended to
 be a convenient  alternative to scp, allowing to  transfer files without
 having to open another session and re-authenticate oneself.
```